# Accordion able to display all but i only need one opened at any one time

Tags: javascript, accordion, bootstrapping

First thing first. Merry Christmas.

I am using an accordion script at http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/4OlpK, which is fine so far. However, I need the collapse option when an accordion option is being clicked. At the moment, all can be open. I only need one accordion option to be opened at any one time.

Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you Js function like below it will work

```
$(function() {
  $(".expand").on( "click", function() {
  $(".expand").find(">:first-child").text("+");
  $(".detail").css("display","none");
    $(this).next().slideToggle(200);
    $expand = $(this).find(">:first-child");

    if($expand.text() == "+") {
      $expand.text("-");
    } else {
      $expand.text("+");
    }
  });
});
```

Find this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/28191/).

Answer (score 0):

Replace your javascript with this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".expand").on( "click", function() {
    if($(this).next().css("display")=="none"){
      $(".expand").next().css("display","none");
      $expandold = $(".expand").find(">:first-child");
      $expandold.text("+");
      $(this).next().slideToggle(200);
      $expand = $(this).find(">:first-child");
      $expand.text("-");
    } 
    else{
      $(".expand").next().css("display","none");
      $expand = $(this).find(">:first-child");
      $expand.text("+");
    }

  });
});
```

Here's a working [codepen](http://codepen.io/atulb29007/pen/mOYLrr)

Comment: @Honeybeemy    Try this

Answer (score 0):

This would be a solution using the slideUp method.

```
$(function() {
  $(".expand").on( "click", function() {
    $('.detail').not($(this).next()).slideUp().prev().find(">:first-child").each(function(){
      $(this).text("+");
    });

    $(this).next().slideToggle(200);
    $expand = $(this).find(">:first-child");

    if($expand.text() == "+") {
      $expand.text("-");
    } else {
      $expand.text("+");
    }
  });
});
```